# Project Euler #3 in Ruby solution times out

Tags: ruby

I'm going through a few of the Project Euler problems to practice problem solving using Ruby.  I came  up with the following solution for problem 3, and while it works for smaller numbers, it never seems to return a value for larger numbers.  Is this because of something to do with Bignum?  Can someone describe to me why it's timing out, and better way to solve this problem  (preferably with reasoning/info on what's going on behind the scenes.  I'm trying to *understand*)

Project Euler problem:

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

My solution:

```
def primecheck(number)
  (2...number).each { |x| return false if number % x == 0}
  true
end

def largestprime(number1)
  factors = []
    (1..number1).each do |i|
      if number1 % i == 0 && primecheck(i)
        factors << i
      end
    end
puts "The answer is #{factors.last}"
end

largestprime(600_851_475_143)
```

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Once you've found a prime factor, you can divide by it. This greatly reduces the range of remaining potential divisors you have to check.

Using your first example:

```
13195/5 = 2639,
2639/7  = 377,
377/13  = 29,
29/29   = 1, done.
```

This way, we only had to check up to 29 instead of all the way to 13195.

There are ways to improve it further, but this optimization alone should be more than enough for this simple problem.

Comment: Can you help me to understand the logic of yours? I am having a bit thick brain. :)

Comment: An addendum to the hint is also that once you have found a divisor e.g. 5, you may continue on from that divisor (in fact you need to repeat dividing until it stops being a factor of the reduced number). That way you never need go back and re-check lower divisors. The slow check for primeness is also redundant - if you repeatedly divide in as suggested by this answer, and work through numbers in order, you will never find a non-prime divisor, so you don't need to check for primeness

Answer (score 4):

It is going through all the numbers from 1 to 600851475143. And it also checks if number is prime, for all the numbers. So total number of operation is  O(n^3/2) which is should be around 10^18. Which is expected to take years for computing that. You should change the algorithm so that asymptotic complexity reduces

Comment: @hammar Unless Ruby is VB, he's only checking divisors for primality, so it's `O(n)`.