# Trying to find largest prime factor

Tags: ruby, prime-factoring

This comes from the 3rd question on Project Euler.:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=3

Problem:
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

Because this is a puzzle, I would prefer not to use canned Ruby methods. So here it goes...

Current Logic:
num is the number we’re looking for prime factors of.
candidate is a potential prime factor
sqrt is the square root of num

```
until candidate >= sqrt
```

I borrowed this idea from Sieves of Eratosthenes for finding prime numbers, where the algorithm checks for divisibility of every number up to the square root of num. candidate is the number to test if num has a divisor.

```
if num % candidate == 0
...
end
```

The goal is to check if num is divisible by anything (has factors). 
If num is not divisible by candidate, then candidate will increment by 1 until the `until` statement is true or until num is divisible by candidate.

If num is divisible by candidate, then we know candidate is prime and it gets inserted into prime_factor. Then recursion happens to test the newly defined num.

```
prime_factors << num
```

If the `until` loop is true, then that num does NOT have a divisor and therefore is prime. As a result, it gets inserted into prime_factors.

Issue:

The problem is not that it's timing out but rather that it's giving the wrong answer. It appears that my code loops more than needed. I added some logging to it. I am not sure why but I think it has something to do with the recursion piece. Admittedly, I never use recursion in my code and wanted to use it to expand my skill set. So recursion in general is fuzzy to me conceptually speaking. Any reading would be helpful too.

What should happen:
prime_factors = [2,2,19]
prime_factors.last = 19

What actual happens:
prime_factors = [2,2,19,19,38]
prime_factors.last = 38

The whole code:

```
def largest_prime_factor(num,prime_factors)
 puts "beg fx: num: #{num},  prime_factors: #{prime_factors}
 candidate = 2
 sqrt = Math.sqrt(num)
 loop_count = 0
 until candidate >= sqrt
   if num % candidate == 0
     num = num / candidate
     prime_factors << candidate
     largest_prime_factor(num,prime_factors)
   end
   candidate += 1
   loop_count +=1
 end
   puts "outside loop: candidate >= sqrt is #{candidate >= sqrt} num: #{num}, prime_factors: #{prime_factors}, candidate: #{candidate}, sqrt: #{sqrt}, loop: #{loop_count}" 
   gets
 prime_factors << num
 prime_factors.last
end
```

Comment: BTW... `require 'prime'; Prime.prime_division(76)[-1][0]`

Comment: You never check that the numbers you're appending to prime_factors are actually prime

Comment: It would be easier if post the algorithm that you're following in this case. From another question on similar topic, I understand that this is a project Euler problem, so there can be many approaches to the solution. Since you intend to figure out issue with your code, it would be advisable to add the algorithm in words to the question.

Comment: Thanks Kashyap for the helpful feedback. Updated with better explanation of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project Euler #3 in Ruby solution times out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474299/project-euler-3-in-ruby-solution-times-out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like, as you have suggested, the issue is the recursion logic.

Just because you call a function recursively doesn't mean that the "parent" stops working - he just sits and waits for the "child" to finish, and then keeps going. This is where this "over looping" is happening. The code is actually not over looping but rather, finishing up.

You can see this in your puts statement. Notice, after the loop stops, sqrt increases because script now running the parent code, not the after the recursive piece (child) finishes.

For the fix, I did 2 things:
1. Create a Boolean that indicates that the code block has gone through recursion. If so, run this code, else... run something else.
2. If candidate is not 2, then increment by 2. This skips testing all even numbers except for 2. There is no need to test for other even numbers since it's not a prime.

```
def largest_prime_factor(num,prime_factors,recursive)
  candidate = 2
  until candidate >= Math.sqrt(num)
    recursive = false
    if num % candidate == 0
      num = num / candidate
      recursive = true
      prime_factors << candidate
      largest_prime_factor(num,prime_factors,recursive)
    end
    break if recursive
    candidate == 2 ? candidate += 1 : candidate += 2
  end
  prime_factors << num unless recursive
  prime_factors.last
end
```